# Where are log of hive queries that are executed using jdbc client stored?

Tags: hive, spring-jdbc, web-development-server

logs of queries that run on Hive CLI are stored in '/tmp/username' by default but what about logs of those queries which are executed using JDBC client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logs for queries run via HiveServer2 JDBC are created in `/var/log/hive` of the host where HiveServer2 is running.

Depending on your HiveServer2 configuration, log files are created and rotated. The default is daily log rotation.

On a cluster configured using Cloudera Manager + with daily log rotation set,the log file with latest logs is in the following format:

```
hadoop-cmf-<Service Name>-<Instance RoleType>-<Host Name>.log.out
```

and, older rotated logs backup is saved as:

```
hadoop-cmf-<Service Name>-<Instance RoleType>-<Host Name>.log.out.yyyy-MM-dd
```

Hope it helps!!